# dotnet restore on build server says package is not compatible with "net50"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, teamcity

I've got a .NET 5 solution that builds fine on multiple machines, but on the TeamCity build server it does not.

```
C:\redacted.WebAPI.csproj : error NU1202:   - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
C:\redacted.WebAPI.csproj : error NU1202:   - netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
C:\redacted.WebAPI.csproj : error NU1202: Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore 10.2.2 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0) / win7-x86. Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore 10.2.2 supports:
C:\redacted.WebAPI.csproj : error NU1202:   - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
C:\redacted.WebAPI.csproj : error NU1202:   - netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
C:\redacted.WebAPI.Tests.csproj : error NU1202: Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore 10.2.2 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore 10.2.2 supports:
C:\redacted.WebAPI.Tests.csproj : error NU1202:   - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
C:\redacted.WebAPI.Tests.csproj : error NU1202:   - netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
C:\redacted.IntegrationTests.csproj : error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 5.0.6 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 5.0.6 supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
C:\redacted.IntegrationTests.csproj : error NU1202: Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore 10.2.2 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore 10.2.2 supports:
C:\redacted.IntegrationTests.csproj : error NU1202:   - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
C:\redacted.IntegrationTests.csproj : error NU1202:   - netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
```

All projects have `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`.

`dotnet` version on the buildserver is `5.0.300`, on Windows Server 2012 R2. VC++ build tools have also been updated (`MSBuild version = "16.10.0+4242f381a"`).

Any clues what's going on here? I'm about ready to pull my hair out.

Edit, .NET SDK info:

````
  Version:   5.0.300
  Commit:    2e0c8c940e
 Runtime Environment:
  OS Name:     Windows
  OS Version:  6.3.9600
  OS Platform: Windows
  RID:         win81-x64
  Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\
 Host (useful for support):
   Version: 5.0.6
   Commit:  478b2f8c0e
 .NET SDKs installed:
   1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   2.2.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   5.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
 .NET runtimes installed:
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]```
````

Comment: delete the content of the nuget package folder in user directory and run dotnet restore before you build the project.

Comment: Ran `dotnet nuget locals all -c`, but same problem still.

Comment: Let's me know the result of command `dotnet --list-sdks`  and `dotnet --version` on your CI server. Learn more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows

Comment: I added it as an edit in the post, was too long to put in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. From the detailed logs it looked like dotnet restore was using the 3.1 SDK for package restore, even though it started with the 5.0 SDK.

Turns out there was an environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath` defined, which pointed to the 2.1 SDK. Once this was set to the 5.0 SDK, the restore worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/10.2.2

The problem caused by your CI server, not by `dotnet` or .NET SDK .

Comment: Yes, but *what* is wrong with the build server?

Answer (score 0):

@Ben-f Thank you.  Your answer solved my problem.
For anyone else with this problem:
I was able to view the `MSBuildSDKsPath` parameter in the TeamCity server Parameter tab in the edit configuration screen.
However, the path was not in the TeamCity build server, but for the TeamCity build agent.
[image]

Once I updated the path to the dotnet version I needed, the build was successful.